# Adding whitespace to a field that is a FLOAT gives me 0 not ' ' ( space)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE tablex 
set Deal Number= '  '
where Deal Number is null
```

Trying to make field have a '  '  ( white space ). Instead null becomes 0 .

How do I get what I want here ?

Comment: What's the data type of `Deal Number`?

Comment: Is there really a space in the name `Deal Number`? Then put it in square brackets.

Answer (score 4):

Your field is a numeric type (float) which means you cannot assign an empty string or white space to it. When you try then the conversion becomes 0 by default.

You can try setting it to null (if it's allowed by your DDL) or, if you really want to be able to assign white space you can make the field a varchar type and perform conversions when you need to calculate it. That's not recommended though. It's better to deal with a null value. (I'm guess that you want to display 'nothing' in a client application when there's no value in the field.)

Comment: More has to do with the server trying to parse the string to a number and whitespace is being parsed to 0 (default value of a float type since conversion failed). However, setting `Deal Number = '3.14'` would give you the desired result (a numeric of 3.14) because it was in-fact able to be parsed as a numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a numeric field to an empty **string**, since an empty **string** is a **string**.

Change your data type, or change your application/display layer to display `''` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Empty strings (whitespace strings are empty due to ANSI standard) converted to numeric gives 0.

Use nvarchar(n) type instead if float to store strings